# Проблемы с kernel на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

Пытаюсь устанавоить драйвера Dahdi для ASterisk и выдает вот такую ошибку.

```
You do not appear to have the sources for the 4.4.0-51-generic kernel installed.
```

Я так понимаю проблема в отсутствии исходников для данного ядра? Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: что выводит `uname -r`?

Comment: 4-ая версия,точные цифры не помню

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/266396/416190

Comment: Спасибо дома попробую

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет это:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source linux-headers-generic
```